# Typescript can't return, no matter what not even using callbacks

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I can't return no matter what I do.
This is my function (nestjs)

```js
async registerUser(body: UserInterface): Promise<string>
```

I tried everything, nothing works. I've read that callback might help, but I can't return even using a callback.

```js
        await this.startRegistration(userBuilder, (result) => {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
```

The console log works, but the function doesn't return. When I try to assign the result to a value,

```js
        let testResult: any; 

        await this.startRegistration(userBuilder, (result) => {
            console.log(result);
            testResult = result;
            return result;
        });
        return testResult;
```

it just returns undefined...

my start registration func:

```js
async startRegistration(userBuilder: UserInterface, callback: (result: string) => void)
```

I am trying to call the callback this way:

```js
callback(JSON.stringify({error: "SUCCESS", errorCode: 10}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await this.startRegistration(userBuilder, (result) => {
  console.log(result);
  return result;
});
```

`await` only works with promises. It looks like startRegistration is not using promises, so you'll have to wrap it in one.

```
const promise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.startRegistration(userBuilder, (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    resolve(result);
  });
})

const testResult = await promise;
```

or shorter:

```
const testResult = await new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
  this.startRegistration(userBuilder, resolve);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks to you I fixed it. https://hastebin.com/moradekeqo.js

Answer (score 0):

```
 let testResult: any; 

        testResult = this.startRegistration(userBuilder, (result) => {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
        return testResult;
```

and startRegistration()

```
startRegistration(userBuilder: UserInterface, callback: (result: string) => string) {
    //operations
    return callback()
}
```

No need to use `async` until you are returning a promise.
I  guess this will get you started.

if you are returning promise,

it is necessary to have your `await` inside an `async` function

```
async someFunction() {
   let testResult: any; 

        testResult = await this.startRegistration(userBuilder, (result) => {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
        return testResult;
}
```